# pulse audio volume control

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

having some trouble with pulse audio volume control.

When run it, I get the error message you can see in the window in the screen shot below.

[image]

However when I run `start-pulseaudio-x11` in the terminal, you can see the output is "unknown job".

Does anybody know what I could do to get pulse audio volume control working again?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. After some investigating, this worked for me.

First, go to the Terminal. 
Type `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Next, type `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`
and finally, type `sudo alsa force-reload`

I hope this helps.